# Is there a database that provides chapter lengths of books?

Tags: api, database, books

I'm trying to test an idea regarding the chapter lengths of various books. I was wondering if there's a database I can query for this information? This similar to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/is-there-a-database-that-provides-lengths-of-books), though I would like to have more granular data than the average chapter length of a book.